# Clean repository for every configuration when running multiple configurations in one build definition

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I am trying to run multiple configurations under one build definition on TFS using Visual Studio 2013. Is it possible to specify that i want a clean repository before building each configuration?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. When you are in the build configuration settings (right-click on the build and select 'edit build definition') you should see the option "Clean Repository" with a "False". Change this to "True".