# Is it possible to stop my Build definition Creating a brand new workspace for every run on my Build Agent?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

So I am using `VSTF` with some On Site build agents. A **Windows Machine** and a **Mac** for `Xanamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android` builds and `TFS` for source control

Each time the build definition runs it creates a **brand new workspace** where it downloads and builds my application. This means that my list of `TFS workspaces` grow ever increasingly and that my build agent's hard drive fills very quickly.

I have changed the **Clean** setting in the **Repositories** tab to true. Which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26616923/2987066).

This works fine for my **Windows build agent** but does not work for my **Mac Build agent**.

Am I missing something on my mac build agent?

**Aside:** Currently my Mac build definition always fails but that doesnt seem to affect the Windows build agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a legitimate bug in the Mac/Linux agent.  You should open an issue on their GitHub page:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent/issues

Comment: I think I used `Xplat` build agent on my mac, but I can't seem to find this anymore. Should I replace my build agent with this `VSO-agent`. or is this the same thing as `Xplat`?

Comment: I assume this one? https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent  Looks like that is still in preview.  I would try the other one and see if it works better.